# want to install php7-devel for php7.1 on centOS

Tags: php, php-extension

centOS 7, when I try

```
yum install -y php7-devel
```

I got No package php7-devel available.Error: Nothing to do.
I want use [php-x](https://github.com/swoole/PHP-X), it say I should install php7-devel. Anyone advice?

Answer (score 2):

need to add yum repo. in my case i am using Webtatic repo.

Comment: yeah, I should add yum repo and I use Webtatic repo too
[My solution](https://github.com/swoole/PHP-X/issues/40)

Answer (score 1):

what php yum rep you select?
i recommend remi php repo https://rpms.remirepo.net/
i can find php-devel in my vm

> >
>   xxxx git:(change_format) ✗ yum search php70-php-devel
>
> rh-php70-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions

Answer (score 1):

Which is you current PHP provider ?

CentOS provides PHP 5.4, and package name is **php-devel**

For more recent version, official solution (from Red Hat) is to use Software Collection which provide php 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 which can be installed beside default version (without altering the base system).

You can read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/). In this case, package name is **rh-php71-php-devel**

Else you have to use some 3rd party repository.

Mine being a solution (dedicated PHP repository, with most extensions already packaged), see the [Configuration Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/). In this case, package name is **php-devel** (with the simplest "Single version" installation).

P.S. php-x not there for now, as I don't need it, no other extension use it.